# HTML5 pattern regex doesn't approve my [correct] regex past the "@" for an email validation

Tags: regex, html, validation

This is my regex code that does work with jQuery validation library:

`return /^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\s\w\+-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{1,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}\s*(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?)$/i`

Adding it to an other HTML5 page without the jQuery validator results an error:

> Pattern attribute value
>   /^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\s\w+-]+(?:.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+.)*\w[\w-]{1,66}).([a-z]{2,6}\s*(?:.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@[?((25[0-5].|2[0-4][0-9].|1[0-9]{2}.|[0-9]{1,2}.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}).){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})]?)$/i
>   is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid
>   regular expression:
>   //^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\s\w+-]+(?:.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+.)*\w[\w-]{1,66}).([a-z]{2,6}\s*(?:.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@[?((25[0-5].|2[0-4][0-9].|1[0-9]{2}.|[0-9]{1,2}.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}).){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})]?)$/i/:
>   Invalid character class

Not allowing:

- a
- aa
- potato@

Allowing:

- potato@g
- potato@gmail.com

This is the HTML code:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="" required="true" class="input-xlarge" pattern='/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\s\w\+-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{1,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}\s*(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?)$/i'>
```

Comment: You already indicated the type of the input as `email`. No need to pass a regex (it won't be taken into account). Or use `type="text"`.

Comment: I'd recommend a manual binary search for the issue. Delete half the regular expression, see if the error persists. Now you know which half has the issue. Keep going until you spot it.

Comment: Also, read up on why it's a really bad idea to use a regular expression like this to try to validate email addresses. I don't have any links handy, but it's been discussed a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invalid character class is `[\w-\s]`. This range doesn't make sense. I think you mean `[\w\s-]` (not a range). With that change, dropping the `/^` and `$/i` around the expression, and `type="text"` so the pattern is actually applied, things seem to "work." But again, please don't try to use a regular expression to validate email addresses.

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="" required="true" class="input-xlarge" pattern='(("[\w\s-]+")|([\s\w\+-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w\s-]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{1,66})\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}\s*(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?)'>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT**

Per the discussion in the comments below, maybe `[\w-\s]` *is* meant to be a range, so my edit (although getting rid of the error) is perhaps not semantically the same as the JavaScript interpretation of the original pattern.

Comment: `/[\w-\s]/`  is a correct pattern in JS regex, `/[\w-\s]/u` is not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, what/where is the `/u`?

Comment: In ES6, the HTML5 `pattern` is compiled with the `/u` modifier by default.

Comment: A kind of Unicode. See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex. And you are right, the `-` in between `\w` and `\s` is treated as a range operator by ES6, thus, you need to either escape it or put at the start/end of the character class.

Comment: Also, if you drop `/i`, you need to turn `[a-z]` into `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. I believe that there's no way to use a case-insensitive modifier in this context, so I think that's a necessary change.